# Converting PDO Array to Mysqli Array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, pdo

I am trying to convert this PDO to Mysqli. This is a simple array that I am using to insert data into a table from my database.

Here is the original PDO code:

```
if(isset($_POST["item_name"]))
{
 include('database_connection.php');

 for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["item_name"]); $count++)
 {
  $data = array(
   ':item_name'   => $_POST["item_name"][$count],
   ':item_category_id'  => $_POST["item_category"][$count],
   ':item_sub_category_id' => $_POST["item_sub_category"][$count]
  );

  $query = "
   INSERT INTO items 
       (item_name, item_category_id, item_sub_category_id) 
       VALUES (:item_name, :item_category_id, :item_sub_category_id)
  ";

  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

  $statement->execute($data);
 }

 echo 'ok';
}
```

Here is my attempt at changing it to mysqli:

```
<?php

//insert.php;

if(isset($_POST["item_name"]))
{
 include('database_connection.php');

 for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["item_name"]); $count++)
 {
  $data = array(
   ':item_name'   => $_POST["item_name"][$count],
   ':item_category_id'  => $_POST["item_category"][$count],
   ':item_sub_category_id' => $_POST["item_sub_category"][$count]
  );

  $statement=$connect->prepare(" 
   INSERT INTO items 
       (item_name, item_category_id, item_sub_category_id) 
       VALUES (:item_name, :item_category_id, :item_sub_category_id)
  ");


  $statement->execute($data);
 }

 echo 'ok';
}


?>
```

I can't seem to figure this out. The 'for' loop & array look like they can stay the same - so I just edited my prepare and execute for mysqli but it's not working.

Comment: Why would you bother with this conversion

Comment: because my whole project is in mysqli which is what im currently learning

Comment: mysqli doesn't use named parameters, so `:item_name, :item_category_id, :item_sub_category_id` won't work. I'd suggest reading [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) which explains how mysqli uses parameter binding

Comment: _because my whole project is in mysqli_ Then I have to ask where did the PDO code come from

Comment: _Side note:_ If possible, I would rather recommend that you switch out mysqli to PDO. PDO has an easier API and have some extra features (like named parameters, different fetch modes etc) that makes life easier.

Comment: And if your whole project is in `MYSQLI_` then how come you didnt know that you have to use `?` and not `:namedParams`??

Comment: @M.Eriksson starting to consider this more and more....just that i have so much mysqli code that took me forever to figure out and i dread converting that and making it work in PDO hahaha.

Comment: @RiggsFolly because i am a n00b and still learning ;)

Comment: At least you wouldn't need to rewrite the queries since PDO supports both unnamed (`?`) and named (`:foo`) parameters.

Answer (score 1):

MySQLI does not support named parameters, you use the `?` placeholder for parameters

Also, you can prepare a statement once and then bind and execute it many times, saving server round trips to compile and optimize the same statement multiple times. **NOTE** That is also possible in PDO :)

```
<?php

//insert.php;
include 'database_connection.php';

if (isset($_POST["item_name"])) {
    //prepare once, bind and execute multiple times in the loop
    $statement = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO items 
                                    (item_name, item_category_id, item_sub_category_id) 
                             VALUES (?,?,?)");

    foreach ($_POST["item_name"] as $i => $val) {
        $statement->bind_param(
            'sss',
            $val,
            $_POST["item_category"][$i],
            $_POST["item_sub_category"][$i]
        );

        $statement->execute();
    }
    echo 'ok';
}
?>
```

Or as Dharman says, you could

```
<?php

//insert.php;
include 'database_connection.php';

if (isset($_POST["item_name"])) {
    //prepare once, bind and execute multiple times in the loop
    $statement = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO items 
                                    (item_name, item_category_id, item_sub_category_id) 
                             VALUES (?,?,?)");

    foreach ($_POST["item_name"] as $i => $val) {

        $statement->execute( [
                                $val, 
                                $_POST["item_category"][$i],
                                $_POST["item_sub_category"][$i]
                             ] 
                            );
    }
    echo 'ok';
}
?>
```

Comment: wow thanks man you're a life saver! I was trying to learn this exact same thing on https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/insert.

Your code looks a little different though since you added '$i=$val' on the foreach loop. Do you have any resources by chance so i can learn your method? :) 

If not all good - i appreciate the answer anyways

Comment: There is nothing particularly unusual about the way I did it. Just cannot remember the last time I wrote a `for` loop in PHP for anything other than testing ridiculously large table data loads

Comment: As a side note, there's no need to use `bind_param`. Just pass the array in `execute`

Comment: Its all about the `foreach` loop and the fact that you can do `foreach( $arr as $key => $value)` and then use the `key` to index other arrays, assuming they are all the same size